# Using unity, create launcher for unity application in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, unity-game-engine

we facing issue to check unity application are already exists in iPhone or not.
So,how can we check any bundle id are install or not in iOS

we used Dee-link to open existing unity application.(command used Application.OpenURL(Deeplink))
for redirecting towards App Store use Application.OpenURL("https://apps.apple.com/app/Apple_ID").

while using Deeplink unity not show any error if the application not exists in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Objective-C Plugin in Unity.

```
// MyPlugin.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyPlugin : NSObject
+ (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSString *)urlScheme;
@end

// MyPlugin.m
#import "MyPlugin.h"

@implementation MyPlugin

+ (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSString *)urlScheme {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlScheme];
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url];
}

@end
```

You would then need to expose this to Unity via a C interface and use DllImport in C# to call it:

```
public class MyPluginInterface {
    #if UNITY_IOS && !UNITY_EDITOR
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern bool _canOpenURL(string urlScheme);

    public static bool CanOpenURL(string urlScheme) {
        return _canOpenURL(urlScheme);
    }
    #endif
}
```

Please note that starting from iOS 9, you also need to declare which URL schemes you intend to check in your app's Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes, otherwise canOpenURL will always return false.